# How to avoid deselection of check box in extjs4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell me how to avoid deselection of check box in extjs4.1? In my application the check box should always be selected. The user shouldn't deselect the check box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`readOnly`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-readOnly) config property and configure your checkbox with `readOnly: true`. Value from this checkbox will be normally submited, but user can not uncheck the checkbox.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',            
    boxLabel: 'Read only checkbox',
    name: 'readOnly',
    readOnly: true,
    checked: true

}
```